# Source of tale/story referenced in "The Last Question" by Asimov

Tags: story-identification, isaac-asimov, the-last-question

In Isaac Asimov's "*The Last Question*", there is a passage which reads:

> "Sure you are. You're weak on logic, that's the trouble with you.
>   You're like the guy in the story who was caught in a sudden shower and
>   who ran to a grove of trees and got under one. He wasn't worried, you
>   see, because he figured when one tree got wet through, he would just
>   get under another one."
>
> "I get it," said Adell. "Don't shout. When the sun is done, the other
>   stars will be gone, too."

Does anyone know which folk tale/fable is he referring to here?

Comment: Sounds like it's probably an old joke, rather than a folk tale or fable.

Comment: I doubt it's a true fable.. probably more of an absurdism.  Same idea as the old 'We are traveling to the Sun!' - 'But, Sir!  It's a huge ball of flaming gas!  We can't land there!' - 'Ah, yes... But we will go at night!'  -- meant to poke fun at poor understanding / logic.

Comment: It could be a faketale, you know a folktale that a writer makes up in his or her Speculative Universe in order to illustrate a point. Similar to the stories Sofia would tell in Golden Girls... Yes, I did just make a GG reference =]

Comment: On the other hand, there are a lot of fables and folktales, on lots of similar themes - I suspect even if it was made up of whole cloth, something eerily similar exists.  It may yet be found :D

Comment: "Does anyone know which folk tale/fable is he referring to here?" Is there any reason why the answer isn't "Yes, the one where there's a guy who was caught in a sudden shower and who ran to a grove of trees and got under one. He wasn't worried, you see, because he figured when one tree got wet through, he would just get under another one." ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative, but I don't think there is any outside source for this story. I believe this is intended to be read as a parable made up by the speaker to explain his point, or made up by someone the speaker heard making this point in the past.

Of course, if the parable had been used for a long time, it would essentially be a folk story.